# Zoom Web SDK module not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start, zoom-sdk

I've been working on this for a week now but I can't seem to make it work and I am tired as hell. I'm trying to test the dev zoom sdk but it's giving me this error.

What I already tried but doesn't work:

1. run npm install
2. copy @zoomus to node_modules folder
3. run npm install --save react-router-dom

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I never used zoom SDK, but I tried to give a look for you at npm package.

I did not understand what you did, but I suggest you to check the [official npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zoomus/websdk).

You can see that they have a [sample app](https://github.com/zoom/sample-app-web) available on github. I tried to clone it and run it and it runs well. Just type:

```
git clone https://github.com/zoom/sample-app-web.git --branch master --depth 1
cd sample-app-web/Local
npm install
npm run start
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Upon checking, that's a different zoom sdk, a client one specifically. What I am trying to run is the developer web client

Answer (score 0):

To install the [Zoom Video SDK](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/video/web) via NPM, run:

```
$ npm install @zoom/videosdk --save
```

Then, import the Video SDK module:

```
import ZoomVideo from '@zoom/videosdk';
```

Additional instructions can be found on the [Zoom Video SDK NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zoom/videosdk) or the [Zoom Video SDK Documentation](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/video/web/build/integrate).